# Can I wire a 12V car battery to the 12v cigeratte lighter plug?

Tags: automotive, 12v, lead-acid

I have a van for summer travel and I am considering wiring up a car battery directly off of a 12V cigarette port which is rated at 20A by the car company. If both batteries were well charged at the time of connection, would it probably fry the fuse of the cigarette port very easily? The cigarette port is switched off by a relay every time I put the car into sleep mode.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The audio of the camping car is very tinny, so I would like to have a decently powered amplifier and speakers at the back, perhaps 300W RMS briefly, which is higher than the cigarette lighter jack can deal with.

Comment: If there is voltage difference between the batteries, e.g. one is empty and one is full, the full one will always charge the empty one until potentials are equal. There could be more than 20A flowing between batteries into any direction when you plug them in, limited only by the resistance of the wires and fuse, and the lighter socket is not meant to have batteries connected to it, and the current surges could weld the relay contacts if it has to switch large currents.

Comment: *300W RMS* - that is a nonsensical mix of power and RMS quantities  - RMS applies to voltages and currents and not watts (no matter what you may have read on whatever site)

Comment: @andyaka ok, lol. Even www.electronicdesign.com › ...
What's the Difference Between RMS and Peak Watts? | Electronic Design
17 Jan 2020 — Root mean square or simply RMS watts refers to continuous power handling of a

Comment: **no matter what you may have read on whatever site**

Comment: Power is only instant or averaged

Comment: and as usual, the SEEE Cabal gets hung up on an irrelevancy…

Answer (score 4):

The issue will be after you have run the audio and discharged the second battery, then the alternator will charge the second battery possibly exceeding 20A... pop goes the fuse.

The solution is to fit a caravan or split-charge relay.

Available at many places and they come with instructions.

Comment: perhaps i'd need a current limiter to limit the charge if the relay swtiches on and lets 40A through.

Comment: @aliential last one I fitted had wiring for 100A...

Comment: That's for a direct battery to battery connection, I was hoping to use the 20A cigarette lighter at the back of the car, the best would be a current limit of about 5A.

Comment: @aliential the direct battery connection is the point, avoids overloading the vehicle wiring. Used to like customers like you - lots of work to replace or repair the loom...

Comment: The other option is a JBL partybox which goes on a cigarette lighter 12v. Why cant i trickle charge a 12v battery of a 120watt plug? 100 amper wires from the engine to the back means i dont need a second battery and im drilling under carpets and through engine shields and around wheels.

Comment: @aliential So you equate a JBL partybox to the 300Wrms you mention in another comment. Pass.

Comment: So i asked if i can hook a battery to the 12v plug. The question was specifically worded to avoid a battery to battery connection. A jbl partybox 300 is 125W RMS on a car. I guess i have to re ask... can i trickle charge a PbS from another PbS

Comment: @aliential Do you find “No” a difficult concept? We tried to help with sensible suggestions based on experience to save you grief, but do what you want.

Comment: You didn't say No did you, you just answered wrong. specifically ignonring the title, you can say "Connect the batteries directly, its the only way to go" which is fair enough, but you didn't say that.

Comment: @aliential I answered correctly based on a better understanding of the situation. As I said before customers like you always phoned on Monday morning with “I tried to fit xxx at the weekend and the wires melted” can you fix it? Money for old rope :)

Comment: heard of double fusing with a 15a and 20a fuse? that's what fuses are for. besides, I wanted to limit the current or use a lithium battery or something from a cigarette-ligher-12-port, rather than drill through my car for an 8awg cable.

Comment: @aliential fuses sure, just tell me if you exceed the current rating by 175% how long it is before it blows? Assume a standard wire fuse just to keep it simple.

Comment: @aliential You intended to connect two batteries together, one car battery, and one lithium battery? Directly, without a lithium charger? That might have been a spectacular explosion or fire.

Comment: If i am going to drill wires through the car, I might as well install a lifepo at the back and solar, it would avoid wearing out the alternator too, I have 200 pounds of lifepo.

Answer (score -2):

The fuse should be fine as long as what ever you plug into the cigarette lighter plug does not draw more than 20A from the socket. Something like a cigarette lighter or a phone charger will not draw much more than about 1 or 2 amps, probably  even less for a phone charger.

Comment: Did you read the question? It's not about a phone charger...

Comment: Did you read my answer? I am using a phone charger as an example as they are the most common things amongst cigarette lighters that are plugged into those ports.

Comment: Maybe, but the question was about connecting a 12V lead acid battery which is something completely different. I.o.w. I read your answer and it does not seem to be relevant to the question.

Comment: Okay. Apologies. I was in fact referring to a lead acid battery as that is the type of most car batteries. Just trying to help :( . Ngl this community isn't very nice to newbies.

Comment: My apologies once again, I posted the question before the OP said it was for  the audio. I did not yet read the comment (the guide lines do say you should edit the question to add information, not comment. I will edit my question accordingly